# tkinter - rectangle hidden under background image

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a really simple HMI, to display different images and name of the file and other information in a lower bar using tkinter. I have created a layout, added the background image but the lower rectangle is not visible.

The background image overlays the rectangle, how can I force the ground image to behind all the other components inside the canvas? The black rectangle should be visible at the lower section of the picture

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from tkinter import Tk, BOTH, Canvas 
from tkinter.ttk import Frame, Label, Style

root = Tk()
root.title('Screen')

w = Canvas(root, width=800 , height=480)
w.pack()

back_ground = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("./icon/sync_background.bmp"))
back_ground_label = Label(image=back_ground, borderwidth=0)
back_ground_label.place(x=0,y=0)

w.create_rectangle(0, 400, 800, 480,outline="#000", fill="#000")
w.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

[image: Cn]

Comment: The image is currently not associated with the Canvas at all; it's a child of the root window, due to lack of any explicit parent.  You would need to put it in the Canvas (via `.create_image()`), rather than making a Label out of it.

Answer (score 2):

Your background image is placed on top of the canvas and so it hides the canvas.  You should create the image using `w.create_image(...)` instead:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from tkinter import Tk, BOTH, Canvas 

root = Tk()
root.title('Screen')

back_ground = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("./icon/sync_background.bmp"))

w = Canvas(root, width=800 , height=480)
w.pack()

w.create_image(0, 0, image=back_ground, anchor='nw')
w.create_rectangle(0, 400, 800, 480,outline="#000", fill="#000")

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you can do:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from tkinter import Tk, BOTH, Canvas 
from tkinter.ttk import Frame, Label, Style

root = Tk()
root.title('Screen')

w = Canvas(root, width=800 , height=480)
w.pack()

back_ground = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("./icon/sync_background.bmp"))
back_ground_label = Label(image=back_ground, borderwidth=0)
back_ground_label.place(x=0,y=0)

rect = w.create_rectangle(0, 400, 800, 480,outline="#000", fill="#000")
w.tag_raise(rect)
w.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

What this does is creates an object "rect" and then uses the tag_raise method on it to bring it in front.

Hope it helps!
Cheers!